# Cannot connect to a WEP secured WiFi with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I brought my work computer home and I cannot connect to my home WiFi. I have a MAC that works on my home WiFi.

I am seeing this message:

> The settings saved on this computer for the network do not match the requirements of the network.

Comment: Really need more information than this, can you connect to other networks besides your work? If not you company may have it lock down to only work on that network. How are you trying to connect manually or just looking for the laptop to connect?

Comment: What authentication and encryption settings are on your WiFi network? WEP, WPA, WPA2, etc.?

Comment: I am using WEP...

Comment: Actually, this is an interesting question because so few people _use_ WEP now because of it's insecurities. I'm trying the solution techie put below when I get home. Seems easy enough. However, @Jay I would suggest changing your home wifi to WPA/WPA2 honestly. Most routers now come with it baseline, and there's almost no reason to use WEP over WPA2 besides legacy systems. WEP makes me a sad panda.

Comment: I guess you got the key wrong or something. also note whether set to hex or ascii.  things have to match.

Comment: Change your home security to WPA2/AES.  If you are using relatively recent wireless (i.e. 802.11n or 802.11ac) and have WEP enabled, you are slowing down your wireless as the HT data rates are disabled.  This is now written into the standard as WEP and WPA (technically, it is TKIP but with most consumer devices WPA=TKIP and WPA2=AES) are considered insecure.

Answer (score 3):

Since your WiFi network is set to use WEP, then Windows 7 will have a hard time automatically connecting to it.  You need to manually setup the profile:

> ## To manually create a network profile using WEP shared key authentication
>
> 1. Click to open Network and Sharing Center.
> 2. Click Set up a new connection or network.
> 3. Click Manually connect to a wireless network, and then click Next.
> 4. On the Enter information for the wireless network you want to add page, under Security type, select WEP.
> 5. Complete the rest of the page, and then click Next.
> 6. Click Change connection settings.
> 7. Click the Security tab, and then, under Security type, click Shared.
> 8. Click OK, and then click Close.

Or, if possible change over the WiFi network something better/more secure like WPA2, which Windows 7 easily auto-connects to. :)

Comment: That goodness that they've made it diffifult of WEP users!! WEP needs to die already.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me with an ATT 2Wire router. To work around, I installed ThinkVantage Access Connections network/wireless connection utility and was able to set more profile variables than Windows 7 makes visible. In my case, I needed to specify 64-bit key with 5-character password, and enter the password. Then I was able to connect.

Answer (score -1):

Just install the software manufacturer of your WiFi adapter and everything else will be easy.

Here's an example.

[image]